# How can I compare gps coordinates from text files to see which pair is closest to the user's current location

Tags: java, android, geolocation, gps, distance

I'm developing an Android app which needs to go through ~100 text files containing pairs of gps coordinates. I need it to return the pair of coordinates closest to the user's current location, but I don't know how to go about finding the closest pair.

Any help that'll get me headed in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: You need a function that computes the distance between two points on the globe. Search the web for "geographic distance calculator". Do not use euclidean distance (square root of summed squares), that would be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

You could iterate over the coordinates and compare each pair with the current user coordinates. However, be aware that this is straight-line distance and not by-road.

For that, try looking at the Google Maps API for navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Location.distanceBetween()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) to calculate the distance between two coordinates.